# LookAt function: I'm going crazy

Tags: opengl, vector, matrix, fragment-shader, glulookat

I must do a homework and I try to implement a lookAt function. I tried in many ways but the only result I got is a blue screen. The rest of my program works greatly, infact if I use glm::lookAt all is good. This is my code:

```
mat4 Transform::lookAt(const vec3 &eye, const vec3 &center, const vec3 &up) 
{
    vec3 w(glm::normalize(eye - center)) ;
        vec3 u(glm::normalize(glm::cross(up, w)));
        vec3 v(glm::cross(w, u)) ;
    mat4 ret = mat4 (
        vec4 (u.x,v.x,w.x,0),
            vec4 (u.y,v.y,w.y,0),
            vec4 (u.z,v.z,w.z,0),
        vec4 (-u.x*eye.x-u.y*eye.y-u.z*eye.z,
             -v.x*eye.x-v.y*eye.y-v.z*eye.z,
             -w.x*eye.x-w.y*eye.y-w.z*eye.z,
             1)
    );
  return ret;
```

Answer (score 17):

I saw you use the glm library for matrix operations, so from the glm code the lookat implementation looks like this:

```
mat4x4 lookAt(vec3  const & eye, vec3  const & center, vec3  const & up)
{
    vec3  f = normalize(center - eye);
    vec3  u = normalize(up);
    vec3  s = normalize(cross(f, u));
    u = cross(s, f);

    mat4x4 Result(1);
    Result[0][0] = s.x;
    Result[1][0] = s.y;
    Result[2][0] = s.z;
    Result[0][1] = u.x;
    Result[1][1] = u.y;
    Result[2][1] = u.z;
    Result[0][2] =-f.x;
    Result[1][2] =-f.y;
    Result[2][2] =-f.z;
    Result[3][0] =-dot(s, eye);
    Result[3][1] =-dot(u, eye);
    Result[3][2] = dot(f, eye);
    return Result;
}
```

You first normalize the vectors you will use(**f** is the direction you look at, **u** the up and **s** is the right vector). Then to make sure the **up vector** is perpendicular to the **direction** and **right vectors** you recalculate it as their cross product, because when you give an **up vector** you can't make sure its perpendicular to the **eye-center vector**(view direction), they're just form a plane which gives you the **right vector**.

The matrix is constructed from these. For more detail how does it works check the http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html page.
In short:this is a matrix which creates you a new coordinate system, so the coloumns are the axises. Then at the last coloumn the translation matrix is applied.

(Look at the identity matrix:

```
AXIS     TRANSFORM
x  y  z  transl.
1, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 1
```

This gives you the standard coordinate system with no translation.)

Then you multiply this with projection and model matrixes (p*v*m), the order is important.
When you write your implementation make sure you use coloumn major matrixes, because of opengl, or transpose them.

I hope it helps.