# Move camera to the direction it's facing

Tags: java, 3d, game-development

I have a camera that has X, Y and Z Coordinates.

The camera also has a Yaw and a pitch.

```
int cameraX = Camera.getX();
int cameraY = Camera.getY();
int cameraZ = Camera.getZ();
int cameraYaw = Camera.getYaw();
int cameraPitch = Camera.getPitch();
```

The yaw has 2048 units in 360 degrees, so at 160 degrees the getYaw() method will return 1024.

Currently I move the camera forward by just setting the Y + 1 in each loop.

```
Camera.setY(Camera.getY() + 1);
```

How would I set the camera X and Y to the direction I'm facing (The Yaw)? 
I don't want to use the pitch in this situation, just the Yaw.

Comment: matrix maths is generally the way it is done, rotation can also be done with quaternions. you want look at creating a lookAt function. take a look at the answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740463/lookat-function-im-going-crazy

Comment: The problem isn't changing the camera rotation. I just need to go to the direction the camera is facing.

Comment: this involves rotation, you have to rotate the forward and up vectors. then you move along the forward vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to get the camera to move in the direction you're looking (in 2D space, you're only moving horizontally).

I made a small [LookAt](https://github.com/MrIlliteracy/LookAt) header-only library for C++, but here is part of it rewritten in Java. What this code does is it takes a rotation and a distance, then calculates how far you need to move (in both the x and y coordinate) to get there.

```
// Returns how far you need to move in X and Y to get to where you're looking
// Rotation is in degrees, distance is how far you want to move
public static double PolarToCartesianX(double rotation, double distance) {
    return distance * Math.cos(rotation * (Math.PI / 180.0D));
}

public static double PolarToCartesianY(double rotation, double distance) {
    return distance * Math.sin(rotation * (Math.PI / 180.0D));
}
```